# UITableView + touchable UIView / UIScrollView behin

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I would like to have a UIScrollView I can interact with (mainly horizontal swipe to display images) BELOW a UITableView.

The idea is to set the UITableView tableHeaderView of the same size than the UIScrollView with a clear backgroundColor and opaque set to NO, and add

```
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView belowSubview:self.tableView];
```

Consequently, the UITableView will progressively cover the image gallery while scrolling -  what whould not be the case if I set up directly the UIScrollView as the tableHeaderView or as a section header.

It works (from a visual point of view).

But I cannot interact or swipe on the UIScrollView which is below, everything is intercepted by the tableView. I thought setting clean Color + opaque = NO would do the trick.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Romain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I understand it, you want to place the `UITableView` on top so its contents appear over the `UIScrollView`, but you want the `UIScrollView` to receive touch events?  As you have it set up, that can't happen because the `UITableView` is going to receive all touch events within its boundaries, because it has to have user interaction enabled.
Consider one of the following:

1. Modify the `UITableView` so that instead of having a `tableHeaderView`, the table view resizes itself based on its scrolling position (you can track this with a `UIScrollViewDelegate`), so it covers the `UIScrollView` as the table view scrolls.
2. Override the touch handling methods (`touchesBegan:withEvent:`, etc) in either the `UITableView` or the `tableHeaderView` so that it manually forwards touches events to the `UIScrollView` when appropriate. This is a nasty solution, but it may do the trick.
3. Override `pointInside:withEvent:` inside the `UITableView`. This method is what the touch-handling system uses to determine whether a view should accept a touch event initially. If you modify it to reject points where you want touches to be sent to the `UIScrollView`, then it will not receive any touches in that area, and they will default to the view below it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I understand it, the 3) might the proper / quicker solution right ? 
I will give it a try and let you know asap.
Thanks
Romain

Comment: Be careful with #3.  It's a critical method and modifying it improperly can lead to bugs that are very difficult to fix, but it is the simplest way to accomplish your intended design.

Comment: I went first for your first suggestion : basically, it works well. But I was not really satisfied by the UX while scrolling in the scrollviewDidScroll delegate.

I decided to go for a fourth option : I keep my UITableView .tableHeaderView, added UISwipeGestureRecognizer on it (left/right), and use them as a way to control the UIPageControl & UIScrollView below the UITableView.
Thanks for your support :)

Comment: I'm just gonna call that a high-tech version of #2 :)